# Kobuki unpredictability

Tags: python, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to run python scripts on Kobuki Turtlebot in order to make it perform specific patterns on the floor. I've noticed that while executing the same script on the same spot, it provides radically different performances. This is an example of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# for robot A

import rospy
from kobuki_testsuite import TravelForward 
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('kobuki_testsuite')
import sys
import copy
import os
import subprocess

from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
from math import degrees

from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion

global stage
stage = 1
global length
length = 1 # length in metres
global width
width = 1 
#des = 0.5  # desired angle in radians - it's negative if angle is larger than 3.14

def resetter():
    try:
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry', Empty, queue_size=10)
        rospy.init_node('resetter', anonymous=True)
        rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
        for i in range(0,10):
          pub.publish(Empty())
          rate.sleep()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass

def ImuCallback(data, angle):
  global stage
  quat = data.orientation
  q = [quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w]
  roll, pitch, yaw = euler_from_quaternion(q)
  
  sys.stdout.write("\r\033[1mGyro Angle\033[0m: [" + "{0:+.4f}".format(yaw) + " rad]  ["\
                 + "{0: >+7.2f}".format(degrees(yaw)) + " deg]"\
                 + "            \033[1mRate\033[0m: [" + "{0:+.4f}".format(data.angular_velocity.z) + " rad/s]  ["\
                 + "{0: >+7.2f}".format(degrees(data.angular_velocity.z)) + " deg/s] ")
  if angle > 0:
    if yaw > angle or yaw < 0:
      stage += 1
  else:
    if yaw > angle and yaw < 0:
      stage += 1 
  
def publish(pub, v, sec, step):
    cnt = 0
    m = sec * 2
    
    while cnt < m and not rospy.is_shutdown() and stage == step: 
        pub.publish(v)
        cnt = cnt + 1
        rospy.sleep(0.5)

def rotation_anticlockwise(step, angle, r):
    rospy.Subscriber("/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data", Imu, ImuCallback, angle)
    cmdvel_topic ='/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop'

    pub = rospy.Publisher(cmdvel_topic, Twist)
    vel = Twist() 
    print "rotation"
    print stage
    while not rospy.is_shutdown() and stage == step:
      vel.angular.z = 0.5
      vel.linear.x = 0.5 * r
      rospy.loginfo("Anticlockwise")
      publish(pub, vel, 18, step)  
      rospy.loginfo("Done")
      rospy.sleep(2)
  #    if stage == 0:
   #     vel.angular.z = 0
  #  rospy.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global stage
    resetter()
    rotation_anticlockwise(1, 1.57, 0)
    resetter()
    print stage
    stage = 2
    rotation_anticlockwise(2, -0.02, 0.2 * length)
```

What I meant for it to do is to rotate to 90 degrees and then make a full circle with a specified radius.
Most of the times I run the script I get it to rotate a bit and then stand still or rotate and then make just a part of a circle.
What troubles me is I don't understand whether the problem is my script or some mechanics inside the robot. Could it be that its bumper sensors are too sensitive and make it stop unexpectedly? If so, is there a way around?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203575/kobuki-unpredictability/) by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-23**:
Can you try moving the `rospy.init_node`, so it is called exactly once. About the bumpers: Do they actually actuate, so that the robot stops?

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-23**:
Thank you for the advice about rospy.init_node, but the problem seems to be something else. Are the bumpers only actuated when they're pressed? Apparently, they have nothing to do with my problem.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-23**:
Usually yes. The standard behavior might even be to slightly drive backwards, depending on what is running. Just try pressing them manually and see. I have not seen bumpers misfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the function ImuCallback doesn't accept new parameters as ordinary functions. And if it's called more than once, it sometimes works with old parameters instead of newly received. To solve this I give the angle as a global variable not as a parameter for a callback function.

---

Originally posted by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) with karma: 28 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karmel](https://answers.ros.org/users/33415/karmel/) on 2018-01-24**:
hi ,can you tell me what the pattern was in your code , and if you can give me the edited code ,please .
thanks